# What is the best way to organize an SDK + NDK module

Tags: android, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

Assume I have a bunch of code for Android I wish to reuse across projects. It includes Java code along with some native C++ code. 
I use Gradle + CMake to build my project.

What is the best way to organize it? What I want is a self-contained 'module' within a separate directory containing cpp, java code, some config files (Gradle scripts and CMakeLists.txt, etc).

When I start new project from a scratch I just want to throw in this submodule and include java and native parts with as little messing around as possible.
What are my options?

**EDIT**: I have troubles making Gradle build native code for submodules.

Here is my main app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.palmkingdoms.pk2_remastered"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And here is a sub-mobule gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

I just don't know where to put that `externalNativeBuild` directive.

Comment: The **EDIT** section makes it clear what went wrong. Instead of `'com.android.library'`, as explained in https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert, you used `'java-library'`. With `'com.android.library'`, you have the same structure of the gradle script, with **android** section and with a **defaultConfig** inside it. The **externalNativeBuild** subsections (you have two of them, a really confusing choice of the AS designers) go – one into **android.defaultConfig**, second – into **android**. Please don't mix the two sections, their DSLs are different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have just described the perfect setup. I guess that only one detail is missing: this self-contained module will be an Android Library module. The [official reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) explains how such module can be created in Android Studio, or how you can convert an existing Application module into a Library.

When they mature and you want to distribute such library to other developers, you can export a compiled AAR that can be used without access to your C++ sources, and even does not require NDK installation.

Comment: I have troubles setting up the Gradle integration with CMake for such sub-modules. Actually, there is not "Link C++ project" option. See edit.

Comment: Probably by mistake you edited the answer, not the question. OK, I will try to figure out how I can handle this.